# C# Seleium Is there one way to find the LinkText of different formatted hrefs?

Tags: c#, selenium

I got two types of href

first

```
<a href="URL" style="">Name</a>
```

second

```
<a href="URL" class="test" title="Title Name"></a>
```

The first variant returns usually via

`GetBaseWebElement.Text` or if thats empty i use `GetBaseWebElement.GetAttribute("innerHTML")`

The second link only returns the LinkText via

```
GetBaseWebElement.GetAttribute("title")
```

My question -> **Is there a way for both types of hrefs to return the text?**

Comment: There is no other way. Both html snippets are different and there are different ways to extract the information you want and you're doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following line of code:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, secondsToWait))
  .Until(d => GetBaseWebElement.Text != null || GetBaseWebElement.GetAttribute("innerHTML") != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good case for creating an extension method that does this for you:

```
public static class IWebElementExtensions
{
    public string GetTitleOrText(this IWebElement element)
    {
        var title = element.GetAttribute("title");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
            return element.Text;

        return title;
    }
}
```

This returns the title if it exists, or defaults to the inner text.

Then to use it:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
var linkText = wait.Until(d => GetBaseElement.GetTitleOrText());
```